# Dialing a phone call on click of textview in android

Tags: android

I have a question that I want to dial a phone call when I click on a text view which also contain a phone number. But when I click on a Text view it returns an error as:

```
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=4564646546 flg=0x10000000 }
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromChild(Activity.java:3057)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2837)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at com.shipface.profile.Profile$1.onClick(Profile.java:66)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-22 10:32:36.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(399):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and I don't know how to resolve the same, please suggest me the right solution regarding this.

**Code:**

```
tv_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String phone_no= tv_phone.getText().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phone_no));
            callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
```

I also take a permission regarding CALL in our Manifest file.

Comment: don't think you need the permission ... my test didn't.  think you'd only need the permission if you were creating an actual dialer, not launching an existing dialer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change it to :`callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone_no));`

and i didnt add this:  `callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

but its working for me

Answer (score 93):

Add this attribute to your textview component within the XML layout file like this:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:text="123 123 1234" />
```

Comment: Easy but works well. If there's no number in `TextView`, then it will be shown without link, no exceptions. Cool!

Comment: this is great approach

Comment: The only problem with this solution is it doesn't support all phone number formats

Comment: Best answer. It can be complemented with this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258635/android-set-autolink-attribute-programmatically

Comment: easy pizzy and damn simple

Answer (score 22):

This worked for me

```xml
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="phone"
        android:background="#ADD8E6"
        android:text="555-468-0602" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

     public class CustomCellActivity extends Activity {
          

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
                     

      @Override
          

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        

     setContentView(R.layout.main);


           Button Phone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
           

     Phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
      

     public void onClick(View v) {
   

     Intent sIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri
     

     .parse("tel:12345"));
   

     sIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   
    

     startActivity(sIntent);
  

    }
  

    });
```

This code works for me. try it urself.

Answer (score 0):

Add permission to call in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

In your textview of your layout.xml file

```
<TextView
        android:clickable="true"
        android:autoLink="phone"
        ...
        ...
        .../>
```

In your activity class. Run-time permission check added.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MoreProgramDetailActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 101);

                return;
            }
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+" + phoneTV.getText().toString().trim()));
            startActivity(callIntent);
 } else {

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+" + phoneTV.getText().toString().trim()));
            startActivity(callIntent);
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
      TextVIew dialers=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.dialer);
      dialers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
                        launchDialer(dialers.getText().toString());
                    }

       });
```