# load text with bold and plain text and call text in android

Tags: android, webview

in android,

I want to make the text in that there is a number in that when I click on the number the call will be automatically done.means call window should open when I click on the number

here you can see that there is bold text with plain text and also there is a number which is highlighted when I click on that number it will bring up call activity

for example below is the image[image]

here you can see that there is bold text with plain text and also there is a number which is highlighted when I click on that number it will bring up call activity

Comment: how many times you will write that clicking on number will start dialing activity?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599657/dialing-a-phone-call-on-click-of-textview-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by below code, it successfully working

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadData("<html>Please use the form below to request a specific day and time for your pet’s appointment.<br> <b>Please Note: </b> For same day appointment requests, please call: (215) 884-0453<a href=\"tel:2125551212\">2125551212</a></html>", "text/html", "utf-8");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new InternalWebViewClient());
}

private class InternalWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         if (url.indexOf("tel:") > -1) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use webView for that. All things you require will be done automatically by webView in itself.
This will help you with calling / Map view / Url opening functionality at one time with out any concern for defining static values with in your code .

If you are getting some string value with or without some html tag then you can use undermentioned :

```
WebView wv = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.go_web_view);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, description, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

// Here "description" is your string
```

You xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hsf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
     >
 <include layout="@layout/header"/>
   <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/go_large"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="195dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_not_available"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/go_excert"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"      
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="@color/grey" >
    </LinearLayout>



    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/go_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Cheers !