# Activity requires FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, textview, xamarin

I am using Xamarin and my emulator is performing an error when I click on a TextView that has a link for a phone number.

The application output has this output:

```
[MessageQueue-JNI] Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
[MessageQueue-JNI] android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Where do I need to set the flag, and what should I set it to?

May I please have some help to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is my application code:

```
namespace TestTextViewAutoLink
{
    [Activity (Label = "TestTextViewAutoLink", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            TextView textView = new TextView (this.ApplicationContext);
            textView.AutoLinkMask = Android.Text.Util.MatchOptions.PhoneNumbers; 
            textView.Text = "This is a phone number 0800 32 32 32";

            //Linkify.AddLinks(textView, MatchOptions.PhoneNumbers);

            SetContentView(textView);
        }
    }
}
```

Where, in the above code, should I place the Intent flag?

**EDIT2**

Here is my code to start the activity, with ActivityFlags.NewTask

```
namespace TestTextViewAutoLink
{
    [Activity (Label = "TestTextViewAutoLink", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            Intent intent= new Intent(this.ApplicationContext, typeof(AutoLinkActivity));
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this error now occurs:

> android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {TestTextViewAutoLink.TestTextViewAutoLink/testtextviewautolink.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()

How can I get this code working?

Comment: [Check this option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599657/dialing-a-phone-call-on-click-of-textview-in-android)

Comment: `did not call through to super.onCreate()` add super.onCreate()

Answer (score 10):

You missed to write call for onCreate function in super class

**base.OnCreate (bundle);**

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            Intent intent= new Intent(this.ApplicationContext, typeof(AutoLinkActivity));
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

The Error itself having meaning

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag
```

Example

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: OP has asked the question in the context of **Xamarin.Android**. Your answer does not work. You have provided code in the context of **Android Studio**.

Answer (score 0):

Setting flags should be avoided as it will interfere with normal flow of event and history stack.

Hence to get CurrentActivity in Xamarin.Android Project use:

```cs
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity

//Now you can start an activity as
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivity(intent);
```

**Note** that this might require Xamarin.Essentials v1.5 or above